# StackOverFlowError : addTextChangedListener running for Infinite Loop

Tags: android, stack-overflow, android-edittext

I am trying to read a value from barcode using barcode scanner. I need to reset the UI after the value has been processed.

```
if(flag){
            System.out.println("coming inside if");
            scanned_barCode.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     AddRecord(scanned_barCode.getText().toString());
                    SetDataOnUI();
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }



            });
        }else{
            scanned_barCode.setText("");
        }
```

It is giving StackOverError,  I suppose since it is going into infinite loop. How do I overcome this problem. Everytime the `AddRecord(String str)` is called I need to set the editText to null.

Comment: make it a part of aftertextChange() 
not onTextChange()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `afterTextChanged` apply this check:

```
if(!scanned_barCode.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
    AddRecord(scanned_barCode.getText().toString());
    SetDataOnUI();
}
```

Comment: still the same :( I have tried adding the `setText()` on the last line of `SetDataOnUI()`